# Show: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mbox{div }a(x)\, d^nx=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> For a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ we write $f=o(r^{\alpha})$ if to any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $R>0$ so that
>   $$
> \lvert f(x)\rvert\leq\varepsilon\lVert x\rVert^{\alpha}\mbox{ for }\lVert x\rVert\geq R.
> $$
>   Let $a\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a continiously differentiable vector field with
>   $$
> a_k=o(r^{1-n}),~~~~~~~~~~\frac{\partial a_k}{\partial x_k}=o(r^{-n}),~~~~~~~~~~k=1,...,n.
> $$
>   Show that
>   $$
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mbox{div }a(x)\ d^nx=0.
> $$

I thought about how to show that and came to the following:

Set
$$
\varepsilon:=\max\left\{\varepsilon_i:\left\lvert\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_i}(x)\right\rvert\leq\varepsilon_i\lVert x\rVert^{-n}\mbox{ for }\lVert x\rVert\geq R_i(\varepsilon_i), i=1,...,n\right\}
$$
and
$$
R(\varepsilon):=\min\left\{R_i(\varepsilon_i):\left\lvert\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_i}(x)\right\rvert\leq\varepsilon_i\lVert x\rVert^{-n}\mbox{ for }\lVert x\rVert\geq R_i(\varepsilon_i), i=1,...,n\right\}.
$$

Then, because of
$$
\lvert\mbox{div }a(x)\rvert=\left\lvert\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_i}(x)\right\rvert\leq\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left\lvert\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_i}(x)\right\rvert\leq\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\epsilon\lVert x\rVert^{-n}=n\epsilon\lVert x\rVert^{-n}\leq\frac{n\epsilon}{R(\epsilon)^n}
$$

I get

$$
\left\lvert\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mbox{div }a(x)\, d^nx\right\rvert\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{n\epsilon}{R(\epsilon)^n}\, d^nx=\frac{n\epsilon}{R(\epsilon)^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}1\, d^nx\to 0\mbox{ for }\varepsilon\to 0,
$$

which means

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\mbox{div }a(x)\, d^nx=0\mbox{ for }\varepsilon\to 0.
$$

I do not know if this makes any sense.

Maybe one additionaly needs the integral theorem of Gauss, but if yes I do not know how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't follow your argument - an upper bound on $|\operatorname{div} a|$ cannot possibly prove this unless $\operatorname{div}a=0$. The divergence theorem is the way to go - write

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \operatorname{div} a= \lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{B_r} \operatorname{div} a =  \lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{\partial B_r} a \cdot \nu $$

for $B_r$ the ball of radius $r$ centred at the origin and $\nu$ the outwards unit normal to this ball. You can now easily estimate the integrand to get $a \cdot \nu = o(r^{1-n})$. From here the fact that the measure of $\partial B_r$ is proportional to $r^{n-1}$  will give you the convergence to zero.

Comment: I don't come along with these comments here :-) What I got is the following: $\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}\int_{\partial B_r}\langle a(x),v(x)\rangle\, dS(x)\leq\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}\int_{\partial B_r}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\varepsilon\cdot\lvert x_i\rvert}{R^n}\, dS(x)$

Comment: You're basically there - just note that $\sum_i |x_i| <= n r$ and you can pull all the radius terms out of the integral, giving you the area term.

Comment: I got $...\leq\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}\frac{n^2\varepsilon r^n\tau_n}{R^n}$, where $\tau_n$ is the volume of the n-dim unit ball.

Comment: I do not see that this limit is 0.

Comment: The denominator should be $r^n$ for any $r > R(\epsilon)$ (which is clearly true in the limit), giving you a bound by some multiple of $\epsilon$. Since this holds for every $\epsilon > 0$ the integral is pinched to zero.

Comment: Can you please delete your broken comments?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand why the denominator should be $r^n$ and not $R^n$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10272/discussion-between-anthony-carapetis-and-math12)

Comment: Some last question. Now I have that the integral is $\leq 0$for $\varepsilon\to 0$ - right? Why it is $=0$ now? And where do one need that the partial derivations are $=o(r^{-n})$?

Comment: Just making $\lvert ... \rvert$ around every term?

Comment: Yes, you can estimate the absolute value of the integral as $\le C \epsilon$, so $\epsilon \to 0$ shows it is zero. The decay condition on the partial derivatives is to ensure that the original integral exists, so that all of this analysis is valid.

Comment: Okay, NOW i am finished. No more questions. Great!! Thanks so much.

Comment: Nice answer +1, also for the avatar.